# How to bind "\" to another key in LyX?

Tags: math-mode, lyx, shortcut

I am somewhat new to LyX, and while I've been using it for long enough to know my way around it, there is one feature about it that is becoming ever more irritating; as a student, I mainly use it for writing math courses and need to do so as fast as possible to keep up with the pace. The crux of the problem is that, as you know, TeX code in the math editor is triggered by the \ character. Unfortunately, I happen to have being French as a hobby, and consequently my keyboard layout is the standard French one. Turns out, whoever chose \ as the standard character for writing code very much did NOT have french people in mind, as its position on French keyboards is absolutely atrocious. Should you want to know, it is written by the combination AltGr + 8 (Alt Gr being a key just to the right of the spacebar, in case your keyboard doesn't feature it). That is to say, to type every single TeX command, I have to stretch out my right hand as much as possible, while blocking my thumb under the center of my palm. It's awkward, it makes me lose absurd amounts of time, and brings me physical pain due to carpal tunnel syndrom; in short, I hate it with a burning passion (try it, you'll see what I mean).

Which is why I would like to know if there is a way to type \ with some shortcut of my choice, and still have LyX behave as if I typed it as usual. I have tried modifying my .bind files to achieve that, but to no avail; it seems that, while it would be very easy to do with any other character, the unique status of \ (including in .bind files) won't let me do it.

`\bind "<My-Shortcut>" "insert-unicode 0x005C"` gave me hope for a few seconds, as it does type \ in text mode, but sadly, it doesn't do anything in math mode.

`\bind "<My-Shortcut>" "math-insert \\\"` prints [\"] in math mode for some reason, which is progress, but not really interesting because of the double quotes (I'm not sure where those come from). The same instruction, with any other number of backslashes, or with 3 but without the final double quotes, only creates an empty math editor box.

Lastly, I would like to mention that changing the language of my keyboard (with Shift+Alt for example) is not really a valid option; admittedly, \ is very conveniently placed on english keyboards, but 1- I would still be writing in French, so I need to have access to accents and 2- my actual, physical keyboard would still be in French, so I would have to memorize the entire english layout which doesn't sound like I'd be saving time.

This being the situation, do you know of any way to achieve that? Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Depending on your operating system, there are tools which allow you to remap individual keys. You could remap `\ ` to some other key which is located more conveniently.  For macOS, I can recommend Karabiner

Comment: As @samcarter points out, you can rebind keys on GNU Linux too. [Here](https://people.uleth.ca/~daniel.odonnell/Blog/custom-keyboard-in-linuxx11) is a tutorial. Changing the working of TeX isn't a great idea. TeX isn't just what _you_ type, it is much more than that running in the background and written in the same language which would collapse if you change parts and pieces of it.

Comment: Most probably even worse, but many editors allow  also enter the unicode character codes is some way. In Linux is  `Ctrl+Shift code`, therefore 005c character   is  `Ctrl+Shift 5c`. I cannot test in other OS but  it Windows seems that is `Alt+x  5c` or so. Other different approaches  could be write in Quarto markdown to avoid type LaTeX directly, as far as possible (you can still do that when markdown syntax is not enough), ... or get used to using both hands for this key combination, although you almost have to cross them.

Comment: Ah, I forgot it was for LyX when proposing markdown. Using LyX you should already use LaTeX commands rarely. Many math symbols can be selected fro the math bar, so  you can simply select `α` instead of type `\alpha`  and so on (although I prefer type commands that use the mouse, however...) .

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz & @Niranjan; I'll trust you on the fact that modifying LyX is a bad idea. I applied the solution you suggested; it wasn't the one I had in mind, but it does exactly what I wanted and so far I gives me no reason to complain. Thank you!

Comment: @TomP I'm not saying that modifying lyx is a bad idea, just that there are other ways to reach the goal.

Comment: @Fran I appreciate your answer, but I'm afraid it is not optimal; as I wrote in the original post, my goal is to be able to type as fast as possible, which implies minimizing hand movement (especially when awkward). That is why, while the math bar is undoubtedly a very useful tool for most people, I'd rather avoid using it; moving one's hand to their mouse or pad, then the cursor to the correct symbol, and going back to typing position is, altogether, a more significant loss of time than typing backslash, despite how inconvenient it is on my keyboard. Still, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I know that is not what you said; that was in reference to Niranjan's comment (which does say that modifying such an important part of Tex's inner working wasn't the best idea). As I responded to both your comment simultaneously, I kind of got you wrapped up in their own message (also I wrote "modifying LyX" - which is fine - instead of "modifying TeX" - which is more dangerous. Apologies.

Comment: @TomP As said, "most probably even worse"... If the point is type quickly mainly only maths, another probably bad idea could be just temporally switch to a English keyboard. Of course this have the inconvenient of  having to be used to where are the others common keys for maths (=, +, etc.)  but the main drawback is if you have to type also munch french text with accents.   In this case, indeed  is better spend time to remap just one key in the OS, as suggested above.

Comment: Based on other programming languages, I would expect `\bind "<My-Shortcut>" "math-insert \\\"` to parse the `\\\"` as `\\​` becoming a `\​`, and then `\"` becoming `"`.  You claim to have tried other numbers of backslashes, but are you sure you tried `\bind "<My-Shortcut>" "math-insert \\"` (with two backslashes at the end)?

Comment: Not sure how this applies to Lyx, but in a regular editor, you could just substitute some symbol or letter combination and then run find-and-replace later. `XX` or `xx` often works, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The LFUN called `ert-insert` inserts an ERT inset while in the text editor, but in the math editor it starts a macro (inserts `\` to the editor).

The default bind of this LFUN is `ctrl+L` (or `command+L`).

Note that there is a LFUN for inserting text, it is called `self-insert`, but for security reasons you can't bind it.